# Filter a Store with an Array

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am printing 3 values `console.log (a.name+a.age+a.gender);`, i need to add these 3 values to an array, and Filter the store so it will return all records that has `a.name`,`a.age` and `a.gender`.

I have written my code, and i am not sure, how to add the 3 records to an Array, and how to use it in the Filter (Where is will return the list of records that matches the filter criteria)

```
console.log (a.name+a.age+a.gender);
var st = Ext.getStore('Person');
st.on('load', function() {
    st.filter({
        filterFn: function(rec) {
            return ????????????????? ; // Not sure how to return all the records that matches the filter criteria..
        }
    });
}, this, { single: true });
st.load();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
filterFn: function(rec) {
  return rec.name === a.name 
      && rec.age  === a.age
      && rec.gender === a.gender;
}
```

I assume here you need to find people having exactly the same name, age and gender as this `a` person. )